# Could someone help me trying to figure out this error that I'm getting in Java

Tags: java

```
private static void randomShuffle(int[] cards, Random random)
    {
        int swap = null;
        for (int x = 0; x <= cards.length; x++) {
                int rand = random.nextInt(cards.length);
                cards[x] = swap;
                cards[x] = cards[rand];
                cards[rand] = swap;
        }
    }
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from null to int

         at Assignment02.randomShuffle(Assignment02.java:283)
         at Assignment02.playGame(Assignment02.java:335)
         at Assignment02.main(Assignment02.java:605)
```

I am new to Java and am trying to make a card game but I can't figure out where I am going wrong here, could some one please help.

I tried a few various things but I couldn't quite seem to figure it out.

Comment: You cannot assign "null" to primitive data types like int.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in the loop body? If you are trying to swap two positions the first line should be `swap = cards[x];` instead of `cards[x] = swap;`.

Comment: Trying to take an array, and use an algorithm to random shuffle then save those values. Using the Fisher - Yates Shuffle. Im not completely sure this is correct at all but maybe you could help? Thanks!

Comment: Ermm ... look carefully at the way you are swapping elements.  Hint: how does `swap` ever get a non-null value in the code you have written?  And what does that mean???

Comment: You need to understand the difference between objects and [primitives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) in Java. Java isn't one of those "everything is an object" languages like Python or Ruby. If you want to initialize a primitive like int, try assigning 0 or -1, depending on what your program considers a meaningful value.

Comment: Ah yes ... a compilation error **as well**.   Hint #2: don't run code with compilation errors. Fix them first.

Comment: [Shuffle a given array using Fisher–Yates shuffle Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-a-given-array-using-fisher-yates-shuffle-algorithm/)

Comment: @Abra - Hah!   Someone needs to tell the author of that code about "separation of concerns"!  Printing the array is not the concern of a shuffle method.

Answer (score 1):

first, replace `int swap = null;` with `int swap = 0;`;

second, `int[] cards` array index range is `[0, cards.length-1]`.replace `x <= cards.length` with `x <= cards.length-1` or `x < cards.length`;

Comment: And the third one?  But here's the problem ... if you tell the OP how to fix his beginner code, he doesn't get the benefit of learning to fix it for himself.

Comment: @StephenC My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

try int swap; instead of int swap = null

Answer (score 0):

actually int default value is 0 it can not be null.
if you really want to assign null then you should you big Int like:

```
private static void randomShuffle(Integer[] cards, Random random)
{
    Integer swap = null;
    for (Integer x = 0; x <= cards.length; x++) {
            int rand = random.nextInt(cards.length);
            cards[x] = swap;
            cards[x] = cards[rand];
            cards[rand] = swap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well to be clear, this is not about the >default< value of `int`.  An `int` cannot be `null` AT ALL.   (And switching from `int` to `Integer` is not the *correct* solution.  You've changed the problem!)

Comment: yes you right but i guess he was want to assign null that's why i did.

Comment: Yes.  I see why you did it.  But wanting to assign `null` was his mistake ... and affirming his mistake rather than correcting it is not helping him.   If you are going to teach people, it is important to teach them correctly.   (Think of it like this.  You might get get him as a coworker at your company in a year or so ... and you don't want to have to be correcting all of his inappropriate use of `Integer` in code reviews.)

Comment: `x <= cards.length` will be `x < cards.length`

Comment: Yea ... there is another error too.